# Notation in Serge Lang - Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, k-theory

In Serge Lang's Algebra on page 772 in the middle there is an expression of this form

$$K(A(C))=Z[A(C)]/R(A(C))$$.

I don't understand what $Z[A(C)]$ is supposed to mean. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more context. Not everyone has his book.

Comment: You can google a pdf of it. But the C is a K-family and A(C) is a family of objects of C that admit a finite resolution with elements of C. And A is an abelian category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $Z$ denotes the integers, and $[A(C)]$ the set of isomorphism classes of objects in $A(C)$. Then $Z[A(C)]$ is just the free abelian group with generators the elements of $[A(C)]$.